# NEAR-sdk #[near_bindgen] colliding with other macros

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, rust-macros, near-sdk-rs

I've put together a minimum working example, and you can see it here: https://github.com/synthesis-labs/near-mwe.  In summary: I have a simple macro that checks that the owner (an arbitrary definition in the context of a `struct` of the contract) has a particular identity.  This is just a simple expansion and insertion into the AST of the function.

When I build this with a classic `cargo build` then the build works fine and the macro expands appropriately; however to deploy smart contracts I need to build for a WASM-32 target; and then the project fails to compile.  Interestingly if I remove the `#[near_bindgen]` directive then I can build for the WASM-32 target and the macro expands correctly.

The error I get when compiling with the `#[near_bindgen]` included and for the WASM-32 target is as follows:

`cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`

```
error[E0424]: expected value, found module `self`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     #[state_safe]
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self` value is a keyword only available in methods with a `self` parameter
14 |     pub fn change_owner(&mut self, new_owner: String) -> () {
   |            ------------ this function can't have a `self` parameter
```

I can successfully build the project without the `--target wasm32-unknown-unknown` or I can remove the `#[near_bindgen]` and build it with the `--target wasm32-unknown-unknown` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

`#[near_bindgen]` causes the macro to be evaluated *twice*.  The second evaluation occurs when the `#[near_bindgen]` macro is generating the `extern` bindings for the NEAR contract, and this *only* occurs when building for the wasm32 target.

By parsing the macro token stream for the signatures of the `#[near_bindgen]` bindings I can drop out of the second invocation of the macro, thereby not inserting invalid code into the bindings:

```
    if input.to_string().contains("target_arch = \"wasm32\"") {
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `near_bindgen` is not playing nicely with your macro. I have noticed that `near_bindgen` only instruments public functions, so is it possible to seperate your two concerns like this:

```
#[near_bindgen]
impl Main {
    #[state_safe]
    fn change_owner(&mut self, new_owner: String) -> () {
        self.owner = new_owner;
    }

    pub fn change_owner_pub(&mut self, new_owner: String) -> () {
        self.change_owner(new_owner)
    }
}
```

Probably not exactly what you want, but might be a decent workaround until someone figures out a better solution.

Comment: This is super close, and investigating this ultimately led me to discover that the macro was being executed twice! Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Replacing the state_safe macro with the code it generates?

```
#[near_bindgen]
impl Contract {
    pub fn change_owner(&mut self, new_owner: String) {
        assert_eq!(env::signer_account_id(), self.owner, "Only the owner can perform this action");
        self.owner = new_owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid work around, but doesn't actually address the core issue.